# Mysql: Select rows from a join table where 'in' and 'not in' criteria are used

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables like below:

Table media:

```
+------------------------+ 
| media_id | media_name  | 
+------------------------+ 
| 1        | item1       | 
| 2        | item2       | 
| 3        | item3       | 
+------------------------+
```

Join Table mediatag:

```
+--------------------+ 
| media_id | tag_id  | 
+--------------------+ 
| 1        | 1       | 
| 1        | 2       | 
| 2        | 1       | 
| 3        | 1       | 
| 3        | 3       | 
+--------------------+
```

Table tag:

```
+--------------------+ 
| tag_id | tag_name  | 
+--------------------+ 
| 1      | blue      | 
| 2      | red       | 
| 3      | white     | 
| 4      | green     | 
+--------------------+
```

I wish retrieve all medias that have 'blue' and 'white' tags but without medias that have 'red' tag.

So in my example, the result must be: **item2**, **item3**

I tried this query but obviously the item1 is displayed:

```
SELECT m.media_id, media_name FROM media AS m 
INNER JOIN mediatag AS mag ON m.media_id = mag.media_id 
WHERE tag_id = '1' OR tag_id = '3' AND tag_id !='2';
```

how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group your data and select only those groups having the conditions you mention

```
SELECT m.media_id, m.media_name 
FROM media AS m 
INNER JOIN mediatag AS mag ON m.media_id = mag.media_id 
GROUP BY m.media_id, m.media_name 
HAVING sum(tag_id in (1,3)) > 0 
   AND sum(tag_id = 2) = 0
```

Comment: Are you sure?
It seems to retrieve only **item3** because item2 not matches 'white' tag.

Comment: @juergend I think they want blue OR white tags that don't have red. Seems like you can change the query like this demo - http://rextester.com/NRGGU92783

Comment: Question:

Why have you added a new jointure : **INNER JOIN tag t on mt.tag_id = t.tag_id** ?  

It seems to work without it.

Comment: @mytom I added that while I was testing and didn't remove it, yes it can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

From your desired result, it seems like you want that to actually be blue **OR** white without red. You can use similar logic but change it to use an OR:

```
SELECT m.media_id, m.media_name
FROM media AS m 
INNER JOIN mediatag AS mt 
    ON m.media_id = mt.media_id 
GROUP BY m.media_id, m.media_name
HAVING (sum(mt.tag_id = 1) > 0 OR sum(mt.tag_id = 3) > 0)
   AND sum(mt.tag_id = 2) = 0;
```

See this [demo](http://rextester.com/NRGGU92783).

If you didn't want to use the conditional logic in the `HAVING` clause, you could also write this as a `NOT EXISTS` query and get the same result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.media_id, m.media_name
FROM media AS m 
INNER JOIN mediatag AS mt 
    ON m.media_id = mt.media_id 
WHERE mt.tag_id in (1, 3)
    and not exists (SELECT 1
                    FROM mediatag mt2
                    WHERE m.media_id = mt2.media_id
                        and mt2.tag_id = 2);
```

See another [demo](http://rextester.com/LYA95435).

Comment: thanks! i will try theses solutions.
Difference of performance?

Answer (score 0):

I would do a left outer join on a sub select of media that matches the rows you want to exclude, then in the `where` say `media_id IS NULL`

```
SELECT *
FROM media AS a 
INNER JOIN mediatag AS b ON a.media_id = b.media_id
INNER JOIN tag c ON b.tag_id = c.tag_id AND c.tag_name = 'blue'
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT a.media_id
    FROM media AS a 
    INNER JOIN mediatag AS b ON a.media_id = b.media_id
    INNER JOIN tag c ON b.tag_id = c.tag_id AND c.tag_name = 'red'
) d ON a.media_id = d.media_id
WHERE d.media_id IS NULL;
```